# In oracle database, does Default SYSDATE not store the time?

Tags: sql, oracle

In an oracle database, I have a table that has a column that stores the registration date. For that column, I have used SYSDATE as Default to automatically store the date and time of the registration. When I checked last time it stored the date and time but when I checked it today it returns "17-OCT-15 00:00:00" and has lost the time.
This is the code I used

```
select id, to_char(registration_date, 'DD-MON-yy HH24:MI:ss') from customer order by id
```

Is this a glitch? Can anyone explain what has happened?

Comment: Unless you have a trigger or other mechanism, the time should be stored in the `date` column.  How are you retrieving the time?

Comment: I am retriving it by to_char(registration_date, 'HH24:MI:ss')

Comment: Then why it returned `17-OCT-15 00:00:00` ? Means why date, month and year is there if you are only retrieving the time portion. Show us the exact code.

Comment: That is only the **default**. If someone inserted (or updated) that row with an explicit value given to the registration date, that value was used; the default is only used when the registration date is not given in the `insert` statement. Do you assume that back then, in 2015, the value used was the default, rather than it being given explicitly?

Comment: please edit the question show the DLL and complete sql query details, not snippets. thanks

Comment: This is the code I used
select id, to_char(registration_date, 'DD-MON-yy HH24:MI:ss') from customer order by id
This is not a real business table. I am using it to learn.

Comment: Oh... The interesting part, then, is to show us how you are populating the table. Keep in mind, if you SELECT ... FROM (some-other-table), and if the other table has the registration date column also, your default will never be used.

Comment: My guess - some code has done this common mistake:   insert into ... values  (to_date(sysdate))  which takes the date, converts it to a char because to_date takes a char input, which hence lops off the time due to the default format, and then converts back to a date.

Comment: Are you using only SQL to `INSERT` the data or are you using 3rd party application (such as Java, etc.) where you are passing the date value as bind parameter? If it is the latter then be careful that you are using a bind variable data type that supports Date and Time rather than just a Date data type as that will set the time component in Oracle to midnight.

Comment: I am using just SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often the simplest explanation is the right one.

"Default" means that if an `insert` statement does not specify a value for registration date, the then-current value of `sysdate` will be used (instead of NULL, which is the "default" default).

It is entirely possible that when that row was inserted, the registration date was explicitly given as 17-OCT-(20)15 with time-of-day of 00:00:00. It is also possible that the default `sysdate` was used on insert, but then someone updated that row for whatever reason, and used a date with time-of-day of 00:00:00.

On the other hand, if you find that ALL registration dates have 00:00:00 time-of-day, you need to inspect the table for triggers, but ALSO the process used to create new rows. For example, new rows may be created through a procedure (taking inputs from your users), and the procedure has an `insert` statement that does give an explicit value to registration date - perhaps using `to_date` with format model `dd-MON-rr` (so, in fact, the default in the table is never used).

EDIT: You show in a Comment under your question that this is a "practice" table. If you created it or populated it using a SELECT statement against another table (like: `create table t as select * from another_table`), if the other table has the registration date column too, your default will not be used (when rows in the new table are generated from rows in the existing table).